# Print array to excel sheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to print an array to an excel sheet starting at a defined cell i.e C3 down until it is complete is there anyway to created a loop to print the array?

Currently printing each value like this:

```
Dim difference(0 To 41) As Long
For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Differences").UsedRange
    Dim col As Long
    col = mycell.Column
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Differences").Cells(mycell.Row,mycell.Column).Interior.Color = vbRed Then
        difference(col) = difference(col) + 1
    End If
Next mycell

Sheets("Summary").Cells(47, 3) = difference(0)
Sheets("Summary").Cells(48, 3) = difference(1)
Sheets("Summary").Cells(49, 3) = difference(2)
etc.
```

This becomes rather tedious when you are print out 42 different values! So I need an easier way to print the array from a starting cell down to the end cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Sheets("Summary").Cells(47, 3).Resize(Ubound(difference) + 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(difference)
```

If you declare the original array as 2D and start the indices at 1, you can simplify the output as you won't need the `Transpose`.

Comment: Thanks, this works! However it seems to print "#N/A" at the end for some reason

Comment: That would only happen if you resized the range to one larger than the actual array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this loop:

```
Dim i
for i = 0 to to UBound(difference())
 Sheets("Summary").Cells(47 + i,3).Value = difference(i)
Next i
```

That's assuming you want to start pasting in cell 47.  Change that number to whatever cell you need to start with.